# Make sudo not ask for password for n minutes after login

Tags: ssh, sudo, password

I regularly log in to boxen via SSH, and run update and so forth as root, using `sudo`.

I appreciate that `sudo` asks for password after a certain time, in case I walk away from terminals or such. But as I already have entered either login password, or SSH key phrase, I would *prefer* `sudo` *not* to ask for a password for the first n minutes after a login, but behave as if sudo had been executed successfully immediately after login.

Is this possible to configure so that no password is required for first invocation after login?

To make an example of the desired behaviour

```
ssh foo@example.org
[~]$ sudo somecommand
[~]$ #no password asked.
[~]$ sudo somecommand #n minutes later
[sudo] password for foo:
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an idea for how it could be done.  **NOTE:** this is a hack; use only if the words *passwordless sudo* make your eyebrows want to crawl all the way up your skull.

The premise is: we cannot pass login credentials to `sudo`.  So the question is how to have a `NOPASSWD` sudo for only the first few minutes of a login.  We can do that by starting the login shell in `NOPASSWD` mode, and spawning a background process in `.bashrc` which after some minutes undoes the `NOPASSWD`.

```
# somewhere near the bottom of ~/.bashrc
sudo -n /bin/bash -c "$HOME/nopasswd-sudo 60s 12h <&- >&- &"
```

Of course the script itself must be started *with* `NOPASSWD` sudo, or we would be still be prompted for a password.  *And* the script must reinstate the `NOPASSWD` rule when the bash session ends, so that `NOPASSWD` is set for the next login.

Here is the script `$HOME/nopasswd-sudo` that will do that:

```
#!/bin/bash

SUDO_FILE="/etc/sudoers.d/$(basename "$0")-${SUDO_USER}"
SUDO_RULE="${SUDO_USER} ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL"

[ -z "$SUDO_USER" ] &&
     echo "$(basename "$0"): must be invoked with sudo" >&2 &&
     exit 1

# Trap exit to recreate SUDO_FILE for next login
trap "echo '$SUDO_RULE' > '$SUDO_FILE'; exit 0" EXIT

# First time around just exit, creating the SUDO_FILE
[ -f "$SUDO_FILE" ] || exit 0

# After $1 (default 5m) remove SUDO_FILE to end NOPASSWD sudo
sleep ${1:-5m} && rm -f "$SUDO_FILE"

# Wait until our parent exits, and we will exit via the trap
# If after $2 (default 12h) still alive, we assume we missed the HUP
sleep ${2:-12h}
```

On its first run (which must done from the command-line, not from `.bashrc`), the script creates the file `/etc/sudoers.d/nopasswd-sudo-$USER` containing a `NOPASSWD` wildcard for the logged in `$USER`:

```
{username} ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Then on every login it starts and waits in the background until the passwordless time is up, after which it removes the file, and the next `sudo` will require a password.

After that it waits indefinitely (actually, up to 12h, to prevent lingering orphans that missed their parent's HUP signal), or until its parent, the login shell, ends.  Just before it exits, its EXIT trap recreates the `NOPASSWD` file.

---

Tip for the adventurous: remember to always keep a separate root shell open while you mess with login scripts or `sudo` rules.  You wouldn't be the first to lock yourself out.

Comment: Love it :-) I might myself also add in a line in cron or as a service to automate resetting it.